# View not unloading from stack

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm a newbie and I have the following issue I'am hoping someone can help me with. When my app loads it has several buttons that load different UIWebViews each which has a back button. The first view loads fine and when you press the back button takes you back to the main view, however when you load the second view the first url loads again and when you press the back button it then loads the second view.

It seems as though the first view is not unloading from the view. If any one can help it would much appreiciated. Here is my code.

To load each view

```
-(IBAction)displayLocationView:(id)sender {
locationViewController = [[LocationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LocationViewController" bundle:nil];


[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:locationViewController.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

To load the url

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.kingsgroversl.com.au"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

To unload each view and return to main screen

```
-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];// change this to
```

[locationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

You need to change the above mentioned line.
Right now what you are doing is removing the sel.view.... which is not correct.
you need to remove your subviews.
like this way.

```
[locationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I made the changes you stated above and it has not changed anything. Any more help? Please?

Comment: Wayne...you need to remove your subviews not the view on which you have all your subviews.So you need to check which is your subview and then remove that subview...not the self.view.....

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the removefromsuperview it means you are removing from superview.But not from the memory.So it is better to use the [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:viewcontroller animated:YES];

Comment: that has created a loop where the first view (and only the first view) loads and the back button reloads the first url. Any more help.